# How is this Chinese folk symbol related to its definition as a stylization of 禄 or 子?

Tags: character-identification

A common folk symbol listed on Wikipedia is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_folk_religion#/media/File:%E7%A6%84_l%C3%B9_or_%E5%AD%90_zi_symbol---red.svg):

> [image: a circular symbol in red]

Wikipedia claims this symbol is a "stylisation of the 禄 lù or 子 zi grapheme, respectively meaning "prosperity", "furthering", "welfare" and "son", "offspring". 字 zì, meaning "word" and "symbol", is a cognate of 子 zi and represents a "son" enshrined under a "roof". The symbol is ultimately a representation of the north celestial pole (Běijí 北极) and its spinning constellations, and as such it is equivalent to the Eurasian symbol of the swastika, 卍 wàn."

This symbol doesn't look like 禄 or 子, either in regular script or in seal script. Can someone explain how the symbol relates to the two characters mentioned? A source would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

my English is limited.

## 禄

禄 means money. In ancient China, `圆形方孔铜钱 Circular Coin with a Square Hole`(a kind of coin showed as follows) is used as money.

[image]

I guess the symbol you mentioned looks like `圆形方孔铜钱 Circular Coin with a Square Hole`, so it is related to `禄`.

## 子

As explained, I guess the outer layer means roof, inside layer sons.